# return of a tab impossible?

Tags: c, pointers, tabs

wy can't I do tab[i] = "return of my function" ?

```
void    creat_tab(int x, int y)
{
  int   tab[x][y];
  int   i;
  int   tmp;

  tmp = y * 2;
  i = 0;
  while (i <= x)
    {
      if (i == 0 || i == x)
        tab[i] = place_full_border(tab[i], x, y); /* here */
      else if (i == 1)
        tab[i] = place_first_wall(tab[i], x, y); /* here */
      else
        tab[i] = place_wall(tab[i], tab[i - 1], tmp, y); /* here */
      i++;
    }
  aff_tab(tab);
}
```

when I compile it tells me :
incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int[(long unsigned int)(y)]’ from type ‘int *’

Comment: The result of array-to-pointer decay is not an lvalue, and it makes no sense to assign to it. You cannot pass arrays by value in C, and there's no assignment of arrays.

Comment: @Kerrek SB  Would you say the `=` in the following is not an assignment `int a[2][3] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};`?

Comment: @Kerrek SB Historic note: Pre C99 allowed assignment of arrays as in `typedef struct abc { int tab[3]; } def;
def fred(void) { static def d3 = {{1,2,3}}; return d3; }
int sally(void) { int ghi[3]; ghi = fred().tab; return ghi[2]; }`

Comment: @chux: You can still do that. Arrays as struct members is fine. But I said "you cannot assign arrays", not "you cannot assign structs"...

Comment: @Kerrek SB `fred()` returns the structure of type `abc`.  `fred().tab` is an array (of type `int [3]`).  `ghi = fred().tab` is the array assignment, not a structure assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tab[i] (with only one subscript) is still an array, not a single element, so you cannot assign to it (it's not an lvalue). You can only assign to the array by iterating through the elements.